# Toad issue :Oracle type as a datype for a column in a table displaying all the records

Tags: oracle, plsql, toad

I made an oracle type as a datatype for a column in a table. It's fine but the issue is when I have 1 or more records in the table and I click the column with oracle table type it displays all the of the table type with the pointer on the selected column.

This is a Toad issue. Please help me with the settings to display the intended column when selected.

```
create type billing_t as object (invoice_no number,customername varchar2(100));   ---replaces objects with object
CREATE TABLE tab (col1 number,COL1 billing_t) --you cannot keep both the columnname same..change it to col2
```

Comment: Maybe post a question to TOAD support?

Comment: @Raj_Te: Are you and mohan co-workers or something?  Because I notice that you are communicating with mohan through your edits to the question, and also, you have a question that uses the same data structure as him. Just asking, because, you normally should not be editing posts to communicate with OP. It should be done through comments.

Comment: no ,he has just corrected some typo errors of my post

Comment: @sstan.thanks for your observation. No..we are not co-workers and yes i used his structure to put down my query. He had almost everything ready so it saved my effort. Thanks for your suggestion about using SO.

Comment: I am not following your question. Can you clarify? Also, what version of Toad are you on? I created your type and table, inserted 2 rows, committed, and then selected from the table. What do you mean when you "click the column?" If you click the column header for the type it tries to sort and you get a message that sorting is not allowed on that column. If you double click on a cell in that column you get a popup viewer showing you the detail of your type records. It shows you data for all records in the result set. What am I missing?

Comment: Ok, I follow you now. The fact that the popup displays all records is your problem. Unfortunately there's nothing to do about this. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The popup editor (viewer) in Toad for scalar types allows Toad to display the data for the selected column/record only. For complex types Toad's popup editor used a secondary dataset capable of parsing through the type, the dataset containing your query results is not capable of this detail view. The secondary dataset is mapped to a field in the original query. Like your original query this secondary dataset contains all rows, but is limited to just the column you selected. For this reason you see all records. There is no way to limit that popup to only a single cell like Toad does for scalar types.